# Is Load testing with Cloudfront (CDN) is a good approach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, load-testing, cdn

I have an application that needs to handle huge traffic. The previous version of the application hits nearly 2,000,000 requests in 15 mins. That version does not have a CDN so that I need to deploy nearly 50 containers each for frontend and backend. So now I have added a CDN in front of my application. I have chosen AWS Cloudfront as CDN because the application is hosted on AWS.

Right now, I need to do the load test for this new application. If I do the load test with the Cloudfront URL, will it show the exact result as it will be served by Cloudfront?

If I load test with the Load Balancer URL and find out the required number of servers for handling the required load, will that be an over provision? As the Cloudfront will serve my application from nearly 189 edge locations (from AWS docs), is that much servers are required?

How can I find a relation between the amount of traffic that can be handled with and without Cloudfront?

Comment: CloudFront is a content delivery network and will not be an accurate gauge of your applications performance. Is this an API? A web application? Video streaming service? AWS allows you provision resources elastically. Are you utilizing Auto Scaling Groups and CloudWatch metrics and alarms to monitor and automate things? Testing against the load balancer directly would be a more accurate gauge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load testing Cloudfront itself is not the best idea, according to [Cloudfront main page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

> The Amazon CloudFront content delivery network (CDN) is **massively scaled** and globally distributed.

However you could test the performance of your website with and without the CDN to see if there is a benefit/[ROI](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/returnoninvestment.asp) of using Cloudfront as it doesn't come for free and you need to ensure that it makes sense to use it as it might be the case your application performance will be sufficient without the CDN integration.

Check out [6 CDN Load Testing Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-cdn-load-testing-best-practices/) for more details.

Also make sure to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your test plan to ensure that each JMeter thread (virtual user) independently resolves the underlying server address for the [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) as it might be the case all the threads will be hitting the same IP address.

Comment: [Load Testing CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/load-testing.html) (in the Developer Guide) also mentions the importance of DNS balancing, there, as well as some other caveats.

Answer (score 0):

You can conduct the load test with cloudfront url as this is the real user scenario. 
Please check the auto-scaling is enabled for the server. Also you need to monitor the load balancer while test execution to validate the traffic.

Also you need to check the security software/filters setting for compression and caching headers for the requests. Sometime this security patches/Filer ignore the header and it will impact on application performance in AWS cloud.

Use AWS cloud watch to monitor the servers.